# explicit mention of menuItems in highcharts not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to limit the Export feature of Highcharts to just PDF & CSV download  in a react project like in the following code:

```
exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: ['downloadPDF', 'downloadCSV']
        }
    }
}
```

However the entire portion is shown as an error. I am using TSX and The following error crops up :

> Type '{ buttons: { contextButton: { enabled: >false; }; exportButton: { text: string; menuItems: string[...' is not assignable to type 'ExportingOptions | undefined'.

Comment: Could you provide a live demo that recreates the problem?

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have the `exporting.js` library in your project? Also, where do you have `downloadCSV` defined? I don't recall that being an out-of-the-box option (those being PNG, SVG, JPEG, and PDF).

Comment: Yes, i had exporting.js included. The problem however seemed to be in the @types. The code was working in local but since types didn't recognise it, the code was shown as red in the editor.